# need li circle style next to text align center word in all browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the li designs I use show up right next to my text center aligned words. If you view [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gv3m1vot/) in Firefox it shows up just like I want, in any other browser it puts the circles all the way to the left. I can't find any way to make it show up like I want in all browsers. I'll put a simple version of the code I'm working with below.

```
<head>
<style>
ul.a {list-style-type: circle;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="a">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list-style-position:inside` will work.

```css
ul.a {
    list-style-type: circle;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
```

```html
<ul class="a">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry I got busy yesterday and forgot to say this works. Appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help. Welcome. :)